# How to hide unwanted HTML Comment like <!-- xxxx--> in website

Tags: html

How to hide unwanted HTML Comment from website.
[image: How to hide unwanted HTML Comment]

Comment: Comments are hidden by default. Please explain your problem better.

Comment: Thank you fuxia,

Comment: Madam,
I want to hide unwanted HTML comments like <!-- xxxx--> from my website. I also send you a image. please help me.

Comment: Only thing that could help you is basically write your own theme from scratch. So, the real question is, why do you want them not being in the code? What will it bring you?

Comment: The easiest way would be to make an huge Search in files for ``<!--`` and manually delete them all. But as others told you, what is the point since they are not displayed on the webpage?

Answer (score 0):

Even when Wordpress is actually hiding comments in your source code by instant, it could be possible that plugins or yourself put other comments into your code. However that happened, you can delete them manually from your Theme / Child-Theme or minify the HTML-Code.
A Plugin like Autoptimize will help your minify the HTML-Code and deleting all comments.